# Better way to update/insert values using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to solve a problem as well as learn and improve my code skills here.

I am using Entity Framework and am tasked with writing to a SQL table, where I can update or insert based on whether a row exists or not. If it doesn't exist then add it, if it does exist then update it if required.

I have 2 lists, the first list is the EF type from the table that I am writing to. The second list is a class which is made up from a SQL query but shares some of the columns from the table which needs updating, thus if they differ then update the table with the differing property values.

```
foreach (var tbl in Table_List)
{
    foreach (var query in SQL_Query)
    {
        if (tbl.ID == query.ID)
        {
            bool changed = false;
            if (tbl.Prop1 != query.Prop1)
            {
                tbl.Prop1 = query.Prop1;
                changed = true;
            }
            if (tbl.Prop2 != query.Prop2)
            {
                tbl.Prop2 = query.Prop2;
                changed = true;
            }

            if (changed)
                await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

There are 10 properties in total in the class, but even if all 10 of them differ I only have to update 2 properties, the rest can stay the same. So to summarize, my question is;
Is there a better way to update these 2 properties? Something other than a bulky series of if statements and foreach loops? Any info on straight up inserting would be appreciated too, thanks very much!

Comment: You only need to check primary keys columns for duplicates.  Only if the key is in the database do you need to use UPDATE.  If the key is not in the database than you need to use INSERT.  The columns that are not keys do not need to be checked.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions and ask it to insertorupdate; it'll send the data to the DB, MERGE and tell you the count of updated or inserted

Comment: Side note, "join"ing via nested loops is an On^2 operation. Consider putting one of your object sets in a lookup device (dictionary) instead/preload the context with from-DB items and use the context's dictionary (do a DB.Where(list_of_PK_ids).toarray() to do an IN query that preloads the context then do DB.Find in your loop)

Comment: Put `SaveChangesAsync` *outside* the loop. A DbContext is a Unit of Work, not a database connections. It doesn't even keep a connection open until you call `SaveChangesAsync`. It tracks all changes and only opens a connection when you call `SaveChangesAsync` to persist those changes

Comment: You don't need `if(changed)` either. EF knows whether anything has changed. PS: EF is an Object to Relational Mapper. It deals with *entities*, not tables. The very fact you have variables named `Table_List`, `tbl` and `SQL_Query` suggest it's misused as if it were an ADO.NET SqlConnection or a DataTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF uses an internal ChangeTracker. This means that when you change a property of an entity that is being tracked (you queried the lists using a DbSet on the Context) it will marked as "Changed" in the ChangeTracker. This is used by the SaveChangesAsync to determine what to do, ie. insert of update and what fields need to be updated.
Second, this ChangeTracker is smart enough to detect that when you set a property to the same value it already has it won't be marked as a Change.
Also with this ChangeTracker there is no need to call SaveChangesAsync after every change. You can call it at the end of the loop.

```cs
foreach (var tbl in Table_List)
{
    foreach (var query in SQL_Query)
    {
        if (tbl.ID == query.ID)
        {
            tbl.Prop1 = query.Prop1;
            tbl.Prop2 = query.Prop2;
        }
    }
}
await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```